# Burnination and Synonyms Part III (hopefully the last one)

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonym-request

For burnination:

- [sell](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sell)
- [simple](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/simple)
- [solidworks](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/solidworks) (rare misspelling)
- [student](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/student)
- [stuck](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/stuck) (worthless as used now)
- [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/superuser)
- [subjective](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/subjective)
- [support](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/support)
- [system](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/system) (burned, but replaced with system.exe for those who need it)
- [technology](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/technology)
- [team](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/team)
- [thermal](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/thermal) (no questions use this tag)
- [tips-and-tricks](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tips-and-tricks) (despite its high use, it's worthless)
- [trial](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/trial)
- [value](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/value)
- [vendors](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vendors)
- [versions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/versions) (no questions use this tag)
- [vintage](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vintage)
- [wear](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wear)
- [zero](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/zero) (or make it a synonym of delete or wipe)

For synonyms:

- [sensor](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sensor) -> [sensors](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sensors)
- [shared](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/shared) -> [sharing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sharing)
- [share](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/share) -> [sharing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sharing)
- [shebang](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/shebang) -> [hashbang](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hashbang)
- [slowness](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/slowness) -> [slow](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/slow)
- [stream](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/stream) -> [streaming](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/streaming)
- [todo](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/todo)->[to-do](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/to-do) (or the reverse)
- [tuner](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tuner)->[tuner-card](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tuner-card)
- [tunnel](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tunnel)->[tunneling](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tunneling)
- [transportation](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/transportation)->[transport](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/transport)
- [tutorials](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tutorials)->[tutorial](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tutorial)
- [webapp](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/webapp)->[web-app](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/web-app)
- [wipe](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wipe)->[delete](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/delete)

Rename:

- [things](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/things)->[things-for-mac](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/things-for-mac)

Other: Verizon Wireless is not the same as verizon communications (45% stake is Vodaphone's).  While I understand the inclination to use the wiki that it has it is very misleading.

Thank you all for your patience.

Comment: if no questions use a tag, they're automatically removed. Also, what's the misspelling in [tag:solidworks]?

Comment: I like "to-do" being the final tag, and "todo" being the synonym because "to-do" is more clear to non-native English speakers.

Comment: [tag:solid-works]

Comment: SolidWorks seems to be the correct name.

Comment: So then synonym the other way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following tags don't have any questions(any more), so they'll be purged automatically.

#### Auto purged

- [sell](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sell)
- [simple](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/simple)
- [student](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/student)
- [stuck](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/stuck)
- [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/superuser)
- [novice](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/novice)
- [subjective](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/subjective)
- [team](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/team)
- [thermal](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/thermal)
- [value](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/value)
- [versions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/versions)
- [vendors](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vendors)
- [zero](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/zero)

#### To burninate: (to be posted to new question)

- [support](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/support) x18 questions as of now
- [system](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/system) x 105
- [technology](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/technology) x 20
- [vintage](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vintage) x 22
- [wear](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wear) x

#### Rejected

- [tips-n-tricks](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tips-n-tricks) -- Tag could be useful
- [trial](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/trial) -- Tag could be useful
- [solidworks](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/solidworks) <s>(rare misspelling) -- I don't see what's wrong with this.</s> SolidWorks is correct, renamed [solid-works](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/solid-works) to this.

#### Synonyms created

- [sensor](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sensor) -> [sensors](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sensors)
- [shared](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/shared) -> [sharing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sharing)
- [share](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/share) -> [sharing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sharing)
- [stream](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/stream) -> [streaming](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/streaming)
- [todo](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/todo) -> [to-do](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/to-do)
- [tutorials](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tutorials)->[tutorial](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tutorial)

#### Retagged, but synonyms not created(lack of questions/removed manually)

- [shebang](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/shebang) -> [hashbang](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hashbang) --- Removed manually.
- [slowness](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/slowness) -> [slow](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/slow) -- Removed manually.
- [webapp](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/webapp)->[web-app](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/web-app) -- Removed manually
- [tuner](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tuner)->[tuner-card](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tuner-card) -- Removed manually
- [tunnel](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tunnel)->[tunneling](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tunneling) -- Removed manually

#### Synonyms rejected

- [transportation](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/transportation)->[transport](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/transport) -- No questions, rejected
- [wipe](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wipe)->[delete](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/delete) -- wipe means whole disk wipe, not just plain deleted
- [things](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/things)->[things-for-mac](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/things-for-mac) -- rejected, can be achieved using [things](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/things) + [mac](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mac) or [osx](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/osx)

Comment: Solidworks and solid-works seemed like the same thing to me, but solidworks only has one use. things-for-mac is because if it means just "thing" it should not be a tag (useless) and many of the questions that were tagged with thing referred to a program on Macs called thing.

Comment: well, it's [tag:things]. If more questions come up, raise the request and I'll consider it. Will continue with the remaining later.